# Installing CLI fails for Hyperledger development course

Tags: command-line-interface, ubuntu-16.04, hyperledger

I am new to Ubuntu and Hyperledger (therefore I want follow a Hyperledger development course). 
First I have addressed my problem to a Courseware developer (IBM Developer Engagement), and they have advised me to add my problem to this forum (I could not detect a solution for my problem in this forum.).

I am trying to do the IBM Blockchain course.
For this course I have to install some prerequisites, see page : https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/development-tools.html

I get an error message when I try to execute the command about installing the CLI-software, see the contents of the debug.log at the end of this mail.

You also see a message that I should execute the CLI commands from the root or administrator. But I have found on the “Web” also warnings not to do that. And because I am not familiar enough with Ubuntu I did not dare to do that.

Do you have any suggestions to solve my problem?

The last part of the contents of the npm-debug.log:

```
20545 silly idealTree   ├── xmlhttprequest-ssl@1.5.3
20545 silly idealTree   ├── xtend@4.0.1
20545 silly idealTree   ├── y18n@3.2.1
20545 silly idealTree   ├── yallist@2.1.2
20545 silly idealTree   ├─┬ yargs-parser@8.1.0
20545 silly idealTree   │ └── camelcase@4.1.0
20545 silly idealTree   ├─┬ yargs@10.0.3
20545 silly idealTree   │ ├── ansi-regex@3.0.0
20545 silly idealTree   │ ├── is-fullwidth-code-point@2.0.0
20545 silly idealTree   │ ├── os-locale@2.1.0
20545 silly idealTree   │ ├── string-width@2.1.1
20545 silly idealTree   │ └── strip-ansi@4.0.0
20545 silly idealTree   └── yeast@0.1.2
20546 silly generateActionsToTake Starting
20547 silly install generateActionsToTake
20548 warn checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib
20549 silly rollbackFailedOptional Starting
20550 silly rollbackFailedOptional Finishing
20551 silly runTopLevelLifecycles Starting
20552 silly runTopLevelLifecycles Finishing
20553 silly install printInstalled
20554 warn optional Skipping failed optional dependency /composer-cli/chokidar/fsevents:
20555 warn notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.2.4
20556 verbose stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib'
20556 verbose stack     at Error (native)
20557 verbose cwd /home/kees
20558 error Linux 4.13.0-36-generic
20559 error argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "composer-cli"
20560 error node v4.2.6
20561 error npm  v3.5.2
20562 error path /usr/local/lib
20563 error code EACCES
20564 error errno -13
20565 error syscall access
20566 error Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib'
20566 error     at Error (native)
20566 error  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib']
20566 error   errno: -13,
20566 error   code: 'EACCES',
20566 error   syscall: 'access',
20566 error   path: '/usr/local/lib' }
20567 error Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
20568 verbose exit [ -13, true ]
```

22 July 2018: In the meantime I have just started all over again with the installation of the required software for this course. And now suddenly this problem disappeared. I encountered a similar problem a few steps later in this installation process. And also this problem has been tackled by just processing it again. No idea why these problems disappear. I heard also from an acquaintance that he solved the problems for this course in a similar way. It is frustrating but apparently this is what should be done.

Comment: Kees, npm is a package manager for Nodejs packages/modules (npm install 'installs' these locally and 'npm install -g' installs these globally). To fix the NPM permissions issue - you can follow this instruction https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions - but as you've got limited experience of Ubuntu , you could get help from someone in your org to help you do some edits for you if you're not comfortable yourself?

Comment: Installing packages as 'root' or 'superuser' on Linux (ie with elevated privileges), can store up problems later (which is why you may see instructions that say 'don't install as root or sudo'  - unless explicitly instructed to do so - such as prerequisite software - ie where Composer documentation is concerned

Comment: Installing packages as 'root' or 'superuser' on Linux (ie with elevated privileges), can store up problems later (which is why you may see instructions that say 'don't install as root or sudo'  - unless explicitly instructed to do so - such as prerequisite software - ie where Composer documentation is concerned. Another concern I have from above (but things may have moved on since you posted this) - is that you have  node  ` v4.2.6` and npm version  `v3.5.2`. These versions are old and not supported by Hyperledger Composer

Comment: (continued). - the pre-reqs for Composer, which must be used are here  -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/installing-prereqs   PS. you can check the version using `node -v` and `npm -v`